# Why does fileManager copyItemAtPath:ToPath:error return an error, when it successfully copies the file?

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is *purely a curiosity item* -- the solution turned out to be to check the return value instead of the error -- but this code is months old, and that particular section hasn't been a problem in the past (possibly related to the fact that this code only runs on the first-run of the app?).

I have a section of code where I copy a file from the bundle to the documents directory (a copy of JQuery for some html documents to use).  The copy succeeds, but there is in fact an error returned (cocoa error 4, could not complete).  Why would the function provide me with an error when it has, in fact, successfully completed?

I'm curious, at least in part, because I suspect that this indicates some major misunderstanding on my part as to how I should handle error files.

Comment: Does the file exist before copying?

Comment: Pretty sure the paradigm for calling methods that take `NSError **` you must check the return value before checking for an error.

Comment: @danielbeard The file in the bundle (yes, obviously), or in the destination folder (no, hence the need to copy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a lot of example code that checks if there is a nil reference for the error: argument to determine if the method was successful, this is wrong!  Apple warns in the [Error Handling in Cocoa Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html) that this isn't the documented behavior.  You must first check the return value of the method, if it returns an error indication you can then check the NSError reference to learn more about the error.

Comment: Great find. I've been guilty of this myself some I'll have to cut it out!

Comment: Interesting...  and oh boy, do I have a lot of code to refactor now.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 4 appears to be `NSFileNoSuchFileError` as per [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFileNoSuchFileError).
I suspect that since the file in the documents directory didn't exist before copying it sets this error.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for NSFileManager, it says to not use the singleton method [NSFileManager defaultManager] because NSFileManager is not thread safe. Hope this clears your curiosity.

Comment: Hm, I'm not seeing that actually, I do see "The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely", which part of the docs are you look at?

Comment: Read about "Threading Considerations" part also says that creating an instance using [[NSFileManager alloc]init]; as this would give you status of all the operation. So using shared instance[NSFileManager defaultManager] is not optimum way

Comment: Yeah but it's thread safe, they're just saying that it's not appropriate to try to get delegate callbacks from a singleton instance.